# Echo config items in view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm attempting to echo out a config variable into a view and im not convinced I'm doing it correctly, however reading answers on here it seems I'm doing it correctly.

In my config folder I have the following file:

> account/googleplus.php

Within that file I have my variable:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');    
$config['googleplus_client_id']     = "123456789";
```

In my controller, I then load the config file like so followed by the view:

```
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    $this->load->config(array('account/account', 'account/googleplus'));
    }
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('sign_in');
}
```

Then in my view, I echo out the variable like so:

```
<?php echo $this->config->item('googleplus_client_id');
```

The issue I am having is that it won't echo out the content.  Do I have to pass the data to the view somehow or should it just work it out itself?

Its throwing the error:

> The configuration file Array.php does not
>   exist.

Comment: What's the `var_dump()` result of `$this->config->item('googleplus_client_id')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its because of `$this` variable, it is relative to where it is called (in a controller, model, or a view), so `$this` in a controller is different with `$this` in a view.

also, a view usually not a class, so `$this` would not be a class.

instead you could pass your config as:

controller:

> ```
> function __construct()
> {
>     parent::__construct();
>     $this->load->config('account/googleplus'); 
> }
> function index()
> {
>     $data = array('googleplus_client_id' => $this->config->item('googleplus_client_id'));
>     $this->load->view('sign_in', $data);
> }
> ```

view:

> ```
> <?php echo $googleplus_client_id;
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  I got this working using your method, however also found you cannot load config files in an array, they have to be loaded individually.

Comment: since there is no documentation on loading config files over an array, i'm assuming its not currently supported, instead, you could extend the current config loader to your needs, [extending core classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

Comment: @K20GH Use `$this->config->load('account/googleplus', TRUE);` instead.  It loads the `account/googleplus.php` config file and stores it in an array with this prototype: `$this->config['account/googleplus'];`. [reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is because $this->load->config() doesn't take array parameters. You should do

```
$this->load->config('account/account');
$this->load->config('account/googleplus');
```

in your controller. Then you can call

```
$this->config->item()
```

in your view files. And according to documentation in [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html), should it be

```
$this->config->load()
```

rather than

```
$this->load->config()
```